# How to fix I/O operation on closed file error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not able to print the words into the file. My code just give me an error:

> cwriter = outfile.write(line) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

```
 import collections
    wordcount = collections.Counter()
    with open('./tekst1.txt') as infile, open('tekst2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
         for line in infile:
            wordcount.update(line.split())
    for k,v in wordcount.iteritems():
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Could you please indent your code? The problem could be related to ``outfile.write(line)`` not being in the "scope" of ``with open(...) as outfile:``.

Comment: If you want to write to `outfile` you have to do so *before* the `with` statement completes. Indent the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to write to `outfile` after the `with` statement has already closed it. Indenting that `for` loop would fix the problem.

```
import collections
wordcount = collections.Counter()
with open('./tekst1.txt') as infile, open('tekst2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     for line in infile:
        wordcount.update(line.split())
    for k,v in wordcount.iteritems():
        outfile.write("{}: {}".format(k, v))  # For example
```

However, there doesn't appear to be any reason to open both files at the same time. `wordcount` isn't in any way scoped to the `with` statement, so its value persists from one `with` to the next.

```
import collections


wordcount = collections.Counter()

with open('./tekst1.txt') as infile:
     for line in infile:
        wordcount.update(line.split())

with open('tekst2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for k,v in wordcount.iteritems():
        outfile.write("{}: {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: It works but I'm getting an empty file with the same amount of lines. What I'm trying to do is to create a script that would list a word counts for tekst1 file. Instead printing it on the screen it would basically output it into the tekst2.

Comment: So, you're using `line` in the call to `outfile.write`, not a value from `wordcount`. Do you want something like `outfile.write("{}: {}".format(k, v))` instead?

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. This is what i have been looking for